# How to perform p-value adjustment in python( Mann-Whitney U test)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, adjustment

I have 2 one-dimensional lists of values. I need to perform Mann-Whitney U test (Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon) for them. That is my workflow in python:

```
import pandas

from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu 

mannwhitneyu(x, y)
```

That gives me p-value. My problem is that I dont know how to perform BH( Benjamini & Hochberg) adjustment for my p-value. I haven't found information about it on scipy.org. If adjucement is impossible using this command, please reccomend me another way  to perform my test in PYTHON3 (**not R**)

Comment: Isn't BH adjustment a correction for multiple p-values? So how could it possibly be performed by a function which does a single test?

Comment: I fixed my post. Could you please look at these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422333/how-to-perform-mann-whitney-u-test-in-python-with-bennamini-and-hochbberg-adjust

Answer (score 0):

As of SciPy 1.11.0, you can pass the array of p-values returned by `mannwhitneyu` into [`scipy.stats.false_discovery_control`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.false_discovery_control.html).

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(4755221886788)
x = rng.random(size=(4, 5))
y = rng.random(size=(4, 6))
res = stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y, axis=1)
res.pvalue
# array([0.32900433, 0.01731602, 0.12554113, 0.42857143])

stats.false_discovery_control(res.pvalue)
# array([0.42857143, 0.06926407, 0.25108225, 0.42857143])
```

The default `method='bh'` for Benjamini-Hochberg and `method='by'` is for Benjaminini-Yekutieli.